# How can I sort ip addresses on BIRT with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, reporting, birt

I'm a total newbie on [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) and I'm not a javascript pro. I am using birt to create some reports by getting some information from my database. I have ip addresses on a column as strings.  BIRT provides a sorting section for tables and I have this expression right there;

```
if(params["sorting"].value=="startdate")
dataSetRow["r_date_0"]
else if(params["sorting"].value=="enddate")
dataSetRow["r_date_1"]
else if(params["sorting"].value=="ipaddress")
dataSetRow["r_vchar_2"]
else
dataSetRow["r_vchar_3"]
```

this is working perfect for startdate and enddate, but when it comes to the ipaddresses, it compares them as string so in the sorted report, i see like '2' is bigger then '199'.

I could just split ip addresses with '.' and parse them to integers and compare if i was working with python or java, but I'm not sure how to do this with javascript in BIRT environment.

Any ideas on how can i modify my expression to achieve my needs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use in your dataset a computed column, where you transform your ip-addresses in a form that they can be sorted, e.g

```
var addrArray = dataSetRow["r_vchar_2"].split(".");
var num = 0;
for (var i=0;i<addrArray.length;i++) {
  var power = 3-i;
  num += ((parseInt(addrArray[i])%256 * Math.pow(256,power)));
}
num;
```

You can use this field for sorting, and the original field for displaying ip-addresses